# Why is my Arduino Nano's buzzer clicking?

Tags: arduino-nano

[image]

EDIT: I'm so sorry but the clicking wasn't coming from the Arduino **but from the piezo buzzer!** I was wrong and I'm so sorry for misguiding you!

I recently bought an Arduino Nano so that I could downsize my arrangement with my Arduino Uno so I soldered everything together and when I plugged in the Nano I extra made sure that nothing was shorting each other out. But the buzzer attached to it kept making this clicking noise. Does anyone know why? Do I actually have a short-circuit?

Here is the code:

```
#define LED 1
#define twoLED 2
#define threeLED 4
#define fourLED 5
#define fiveLED 6
#define sixLED 7
#define sevenLED 8
#define eightLED 9
#define nineLED 10
#define tenLED 11




int state = 0;
int old = 0;
int buttonPoll = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode (3,INPUT);
  pinMode (11,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(twoLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(threeLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(fourLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(fiveLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(sixLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(sevenLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(eightLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(nineLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(tenLED, OUTPUT);
  

  digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(twoLED,LOW);
  digitalWrite(threeLED,LOW);
  digitalWrite(fourLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(fiveLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(sixLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(sevenLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(eightLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(nineLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(tenLED, LOW);
  
}

void loop() {

while (state == old)
{
  buttonPoll = digitalRead (3);
  if (buttonPoll ==1)
  {
    delay (50);
    buttonPoll = digitalRead (3);
    if (buttonPoll == 0)
    {
      state = old + 1;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    delay(100);   
  }



  switch (state) 
  {
    case 1:
  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(twoLED,LOW);
  digitalWrite(threeLED,LOW);
  digitalWrite(fourLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(fiveLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(sixLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(sevenLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(eightLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(nineLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(tenLED, LOW);
    old = state;
    break;

    case 2:
      digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(twoLED,LOW);
  digitalWrite(threeLED,LOW);
  digitalWrite(fourLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(fiveLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(sixLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(sevenLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(eightLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(nineLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(tenLED, LOW);
    old = state;
    break;
    
    case 3:
  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(twoLED,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(threeLED,LOW);
  digitalWrite(fourLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(fiveLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(sixLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(sevenLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(eightLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(nineLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(tenLED, LOW);
    old = state;
    break;

case 4:
      digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(twoLED,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(threeLED,LOW);
  digitalWrite(fourLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(fiveLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(sixLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(sevenLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(eightLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(nineLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(tenLED, LOW);
    old = state;
    break;
    
    case 5:
  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(twoLED,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(threeLED,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(fourLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(fiveLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(sixLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(sevenLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(eightLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(nineLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(tenLED, LOW);
    old = state;
    break;

case 6:

  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(twoLED,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(threeLED,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(fourLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(fiveLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(sixLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(sevenLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(eightLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(nineLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(tenLED, LOW);
    old = state;
    break;
    
    case 7:
  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(twoLED,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(threeLED,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(fourLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(fiveLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(sixLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(sevenLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(eightLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(nineLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(tenLED, LOW);
   old = state;
    break;

case 8:
  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(twoLED,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(threeLED,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(fourLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(fiveLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(sixLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(sevenLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(eightLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(nineLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(tenLED, LOW);
   old = state;
    break;
    
  case 9:
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(twoLED,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(threeLED,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(fourLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(fiveLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(sixLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(sevenLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(eightLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(nineLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(tenLED, LOW);
   old = state;
    break;

case 10:
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(twoLED,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(threeLED,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(fourLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(fiveLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(sixLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(sevenLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(eightLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(nineLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(tenLED, LOW);
   old = state;
    break;
    
  case 11:
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(twoLED,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(threeLED,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(fourLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(fiveLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(sixLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(sevenLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(eightLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(nineLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(tenLED, LOW);
   old = state;
    break;

    case 12:
        digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(twoLED,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(threeLED,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(fourLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(fiveLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(sixLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(sevenLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(eightLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(nineLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(tenLED, LOW);
   old = state;
    break;

  case 13:
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(twoLED,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(threeLED,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(fourLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(fiveLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(sixLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(sevenLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(eightLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(nineLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(tenLED, LOW);
   old = state;
    break;
case 14:
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(twoLED,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(threeLED,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(fourLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(fiveLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(sixLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(sevenLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(eightLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(nineLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(tenLED, LOW);
   old = state;
    break;
    
  case 15:
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(twoLED,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(threeLED,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(fourLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(fiveLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(sixLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(sevenLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(eightLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(nineLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(tenLED, LOW);
   old = state;
    break;

case 16:
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(twoLED,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(threeLED,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(fourLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(fiveLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(sixLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(sevenLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(eightLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(nineLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(tenLED, LOW);
   old = state;
    break;
    
  case 17:
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(twoLED,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(threeLED,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(fourLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(fiveLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(sixLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(sevenLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(eightLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(nineLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(tenLED, LOW);
   old = state;
    break;

case 18:
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(twoLED,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(threeLED,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(fourLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(fiveLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(sixLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(sevenLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(eightLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(nineLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(tenLED, LOW);
   old = state;
    break;
    
  case 19:
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(twoLED,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(threeLED,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(fourLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(fiveLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(sixLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(sevenLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(eightLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(nineLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(tenLED, HIGH);
   


      tone (11,493.88);
      delay(150);

      tone(11, 523.25);
      delay(150);
      
      tone(11,493.88);
      delay(150);

      tone(11,392.00);
      delay(150);

      tone(11,329.63);
      delay(150);

      tone(11, 261.63);
      delay(150);

      tone(11, 246.94);
      delay(150);
      
      tone (11,196.00);
      delay(150);
      
      tone(11, 246.94);
      delay(150);
      
      tone(11, 261.63);
      delay(150);
      
      tone(11,392.00);
      delay(150);
      
      tone(11,493.88);
      delay(150);
      
      tone(11, 523.25);
      delay(150);
      
      tone (11,493.88);
      delay(150);
     
      tone(11,493.88);
      delay(150);
      
      tone(11,392.00);
      delay(150);
      
      tone(11, 329.63);
      delay(150);
      
noTone(11);



old = state;
state = 0;
old = 0;
        
    break;

    default:
  digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(twoLED,LOW);
  digitalWrite(threeLED,LOW);
  digitalWrite(fourLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(fiveLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(sixLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(sevenLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(eightLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(nineLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(tenLED, LOW);
  
    old = 0;

    break;
}



}

  }
```

Here is a video of the clicking:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TprL56p2YyJ3j8cq43U2LYzaWofZpJM7/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Uhh, I want to see this. =)  Maybe hear it also.

Comment: Not-so-good ceramic capacitors have been known to sing/click...  Does the NANO work or not work at this point?

Comment: How could I show it to you?

Comment: Well, I've tried it out and not much seemed to work

Comment: are you certain that the Nano is clicking? ... maybe the power supply is making the noise

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the Arduino. I connected it to my computer and my computer has never made that sound before.

Comment: What's the nature of the clicking? Can you describe it as like a sound that might be familiar? Is it clicking at a steady continuous rate? Just once after power up? Since you soldered it yourself, I would at least check the soldering under a magnifier and check for solder bridges (shorts). You could take a close picture with your phone, making sure it's clear, and post it.

Comment: Please post a clear picture. It’s very hard to see if there’s a problem otherwise.

Comment: Here, I've uploaded a video of the clicking: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TprL56p2YyJ3j8cq43U2LYzaWofZpJM7/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Éemia, need to get a public link for it.

Comment: Oops, you're right, there, I've updated it.

Answer (score 1):

The simpler piezos click when a voltage is applied, and again when it is removed. To make it buzz, it needs a pulse-train: many clicks makes a buzz. There are piezos that have that feature built-in, but I'm guessing yours hasn't. That's actually a Good Thing in disguise: it allows you to make tones by making pulse-trains at different frequencies. The easiest way to do that is to connect it to one of the PWM pins (5, 6, 9, 10, or 11) and use the `tone()` library-function (look it up if you need to). Of course, you can do it "manually", too, on any output pin, just by switching it HIGH and LOW at rates that you choose, but that will pretty much tie up your processor, at least for higher frequencies.

Update:

> Just why wasn't it clicking when I connected it to the Arduino Uno?

I can't tell without seeing the two sketches but in your video, it sounds like it is being turned on or off, or pulsed, once per second.

Please add your code (both of them, if they're different) to your question. Wiring diagram(s) of the piezo connection to the Arduino boards would help, too.

Comment: Thanks so much for your information! Just why wasn't it clicking when I connected it to the Arduino Uno?

Comment: Okay, I've uploaded the code but how I wired the piezo buzzer is the simply that I connected the positive side to the digital pin (D13) and the negative side to ground, just like how you should do it according to research.

Comment: You've described wiring it to pin 13 but your calls to the `tone()` function address pin11. Is that an connection error or a typo? Pin 11 is indeed a PWM pin, and connecting the piezo to it should work correctly. If it really is connected to pin 13, I don't see a reason why it should click when running your program, but it might very well click during upload if your bootloader flashes the on-board LED - pin 13.

Comment: Oh right, I used pin 11 when I hooked everything up to the Arduino Uno but now I transferred everything to the Arduino Nano and I didn't modify the code. Still, I can't even upload the code to my Arduino Nano. It keeps saying that there is an error. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Please add the error message to your question, and be sure both "Show verbose output" boxes in the IDE preferences are ticked when you run the compilation and upload.